# Reentering the Schengen area when visiting without visa

Tags: schengen, us-citizens, spain, morocco

I'm travelling to Spain with my US passport. After five days in Spain, I'm travelling to Morocco for four days.

After Morocco, can I reenter Spain for one more week?

I've read we have up to 90 days, but they don't say what happens if you leave the Schengen zone to visit Morocco.

Comment: You can, yes, no limit on the number of entries as long as you follow the rules detailed in the question linked by Gagravarr. Do make sure you get stamps (should happen in any case but I have heard about problems, e.g. in Gibraltar).

Comment: thanks a lot for the answers! you have all been a great help! :)

Answer (score 2):

The duration of stay is tallied day-by-day according to the rules detailed in [How does the Schengen 90/180 rule work?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13183/about-schengen-90-180-rule) If you don't need a visa, there is no restriction on the number of entries and no “admitted until date” granted upon entry like in the US (i.e. you don't reset the clock by going elsewhere). So if you stay one week, leave and return, you still have 83 days.

If you were not a US citizen and did need a visa, the visa would specify the number of entries (1, 2 or multiple entries).

If you intend to use up the 90 days or have a complex itinerary, make extra sure you get entry and exit stamps every time to be able to prove you did not overstay. For a couple of weeks, it's less relevant of course.